# How to make my fellow club members communicate with me

Tags: professionalism, communication, management, team, motivation

I am volunteering at a local student musical club. We are planning to do a musical production once a year. Although the whole ensemble is highly motivated and capable we have some problems in the organizational team.

Our club is new, we have produced one musical. So, the positions and their responsibilities still need some time to define themselves.

A friend of mine, and me, we are managing the whole project. The duties are distributed to several teams. We are watching each individual team and take care that everything is done. Our organization has a flat hierarchy. We are not the bosses, but the moderators of the project.

As communication tool we chose Slack. And we agreed to post valuable information in the individual groups, so they are available to everyone.

To come to the problem: We have two persons, who are taking a lot of responsibilities, which is a good thing, but they don't provide any information by themselves. For every task they take we must ask explicitly about the progress and outcome to get any information. It's not that they refuse to give information. They just don't see the need to communicate them by themselves to the team.

My friend and I, we are struggling to fulfill our job, as we don't have an overview on what's done. This has already lead to inconvenient situations. For example: No rehearsal space on the day before a rehearsal weekend.

**So, my question is**: How can we, as production managers, make them communicate with the rest of the team. We'd like to show them that it is important to share the information by themselves with the team?

We don't have any possibility to and no interest in forcing them somehow, as this is a student project, we are all doing for fun and the work they do is important.

Comment: Seems more like an interpersonal problem than a workplace one. Check out IPS SE.

Comment: Have you tried slapping them to get their attention?  Maybe not a actual slap, but a verbal one....

Comment: Belongs on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Create an overall plan in excel, grouped my team and detailing each high level task that each team is responsible for.  Also include a column for progress and status.

This gives everyone a view of what tasks are outstanding and an overall project status.

On a regular basis, assess the progress and post an update to Slack, detailing what is being held up by whom.

This will passively encourage people to stay off that list...

Don’t forget to praise success!